# Free .Net cloud hosting with SQL Server Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cloud-hosting

I want to test my `ASP.Net MVC` web application on Cloud server. Is their any cloud server that is free and support `SQL Server 2008  DB`?

I know this question is kind of a basic one. i am searching on internet and found only `appharbor` but i couldn't understand its deployment method.

**Edit:** 
Updating too late but might help for searching people. After lots of searching I couldn't find free Cloud providers. I managed to get Azure account for testing from a person.

Comment: You could try Azure. They have a free plan, or at least a free trial: http://www.windowsazure.com/

Comment: But they need a credit card. Which for now i dont have :(

Comment: Why you close this question i think this question has relate to developers

Comment: AppHarbor is a fully hosted .NET PaaS with a free feature-limited plan which includes 20MB storage https://appharbor.com/pricing & SQL Server access - https://appharbor.com/addons/sqlserver

Comment: https://www.gearhost.com works perfectly fine for my projects. I use their `Free` plan for development and scale to paid for production if needed.

Answer (score 26):

I can't vouch for them, but here's what I managed to dig up on Google:

- [Somee](https://somee.com/default.aspx) - free ASP.NET hosting, 15 MB MSSQL, 5 GB monthly traffic
- [ASPSpider](http://aspspider.com/) - judging by the site.. not very professional?

You are far better off with [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/). All these free hosts are usually very bad. If you don't have your own credit card, perhaps you could ask a family member or a friend? If they are worried about their card security, it's far safer to give it to Microsoft than any of those other hosts.

Comment: Somee and ASPSpider are shared hosting provider, i want cloud

Comment: @Trickery
Somee disk space is 150 MB not 15 MB.

Comment: @KhaledMahmoud Are you aware that this Answer is from over a year ago?

Comment: @KhaledMahmoud 150MB is the disk space. Database is still 15MB

Comment: Somee runs on Mono, so not really reliable for testing I guess.

Comment: Azure is pretty good but azure does not provide you with free sql server with any plan (except 20 MB sql db for mobile site). If you only want to perform some tests you can have a free trial of azure that will allow you to test on all sql services of Azure.

Comment: https://www.gearhost.com/ allows free asp.net and MSSQL hosting in cloud